# Handling different gui states

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, button, design-patterns

So I want to create the gui interface in Qt/cpp for the server which can be in many different states, and depending on its state the buttons in gui need to be set differently ex:
GUI:

button1 - unchecked and enabled to click

button2 - disabled(grayed out)

button3 - disabled

button3 - disabled

Then after click button1
GUI:

button1 - checked

button2 - enabled to click

button3 - enabled to click

button3 - enabled to click

But for example if server is in different state and you connect via gui the buttons should look like this:

GUI:

button1 - checked

button2 - enabled to click

button3 - disabled to click

button3 - disabled to click

Is there some established pattern/way of handling that intuitively? The biggest problem here is that if the server has a lot of different states that need the buttons to be set in a lot of different configurations. The only thing I can come up with is mapping the state of all buttons to the specific state but well... there's a lot of buttons and a lot of states.

Comment: Sorry, I think this is too broad a question for SO.  I also think you should reconsider your design.  If there are many buttons and many states, the GUI may be very confusing.  Are there any patterns (this buttton is enabled if and only if those two buttons are disabled, for example)?  Can the server states be grouped together, and then at least some of the buttons mapped to the higher level groups?  Otherwise: map state to button state for each button.

Comment: For this kind of problems I like `State` pattern. You can read about it [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html).

Comment: You can use [Qt State Machine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine.html) to indeed implement the `State` pattern as Ptaq666 suggests

Comment: Some kind of explicit statemachine as proposed already is quite a good start. If you only have rather small selections of buttons enabled in each state, though, you might 1. collect the buttons that are common to all states in one or more separate containers to arrange them appropriately around a [stacked layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html) component that will show only the relevant buttons for the specific state.

Comment: You might be interested by https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ instead, it is more design-oriented than stackoverflow.

Comment: @ymoreau when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the best way to do this is just to have a single slot-method (e.g. `UpdateAllButtonStates()` that updates all of your buttons and checkboxes, e.g.:

```
void MyWindow::UpdateAllButtonStates()   // Qt-slot method
{
   const bool shouldButton1BeEnabled = [...];
   button1->setEnabled(shouldButton1BeEnabled);

   const bool shouldButton2BeEnabled = [...];
   button2->setEnabled(shouldButton2BeEnabled);

   [... and so on for all enables and checked/unchecked states in your GUI]
}
```

... then anytime your program's internal state has changed in any way that might require an update to one or more buttons/checkboxes in the GUI, call this method explicitly, or set up a signal/slot connection that will call it for you.

The advantage of doing it this way is the simplicity -- with this approach, it's trivial to guarantee that your GUI widgets will be in updated to the expected state after any internal-state-change, because there is only one code-path to write and debug.  The alternative (trying to come up with the correct transitional behavior for every possible state-change in your program) quickly leads to an intractable amount of complexity, and endless debugging and hair-pulling.

You might think the downside is inefficiency -- after all, we are updating all the buttons even though in any cases, only one of them may have changed -- but Qt's code is smart enough that calling setEnabled(false) on a button that is already disabled is a no-op (likewise calling setEnabled(true) on a button that is already enabled, and so on), so the heavyweight code of redrawing a widget's pixels will only be executed when the widget's state has actually changed.

The logic inside `UpdateAllButtonStates()` that calculates `shouldButton1BeEnabled`, etc, does get executed a lot, but it usually ends up being pretty trivial logic so that turns out not to be important.  However, if for some reason that logic turns out to be expensive, you have the option of reducing the frequency at which `UpdateAllButtonStates()` gets executed, by using asynchronous execution and a boolean "dirty-bit", e.g.:

```
void MyWindow::ScheduleUpdateAllButtonStates()   // Qt-slot method
{
   if (_dirtyBit == false)
   {
      _dirtyBit = true;
      QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(UpdateAllButtonStates()));
   }
}

void MyWindow::UpdateAllButtonStates()
{
   if (_dirtyBit == false) return; 
   _dirtyBit = false;

   // Update button enables/checked states as previously, here
}
```

... then have all your internal-state-change code call `ScheduleUpdateAllButtonStates()` rather than calling `UpdateAllButtonStates()` directly; the advantage is that even if `ScheduleUpdateAllButtonStates()` gets called 500 times in a row, it will only result in `UpdateAllButtonStates()` getting called once, during the next iteration of Qt's event loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using flags, the idea is that when an event happens and you want the GUI to change you set a flag which in turn is recalled in a loop. Below you can see the general idea and concept.

If you change the state of the flag you will get a different output and it will loop over and over listening for events just write the GUI code for each in the different states.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getserverstatusfunction() {/*your code to check server status returns 0,1 or 2*/
    return 0;
}
UI.button.click(true) { getresult = 1; }; //change the UI state when the button is clicked

int main() {
    bool running;
    while (running){
    int getresult = getserverstatusfunction();

    if (getresult == 0)
    {
        cout << "Draw flag one interface code\n";
    }
    else if (getresult == 1)
    {
        cout << "Draw flag two interface code\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Draw flag three interface code\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling/disabling button UI logic can be very dirty and difficult to manage and trace. Also, sometimes we want to be in particular state and want to make a minor change like changing state of just one button. Here is an approach. It's generic but you will have to adrop it accordingly with your UI.

```
#include <iostream>

class UIState
{
protected:
    bool btn1;
    bool btn2;
    bool btn3;

public:
    UIState()
    {
        btn1 = false;
        btn2 = false;
        btn3 = false;
    }

    virtual void setBtn1State(bool new_state)
    {
        btn1 = new_state;

        std::cout << btn1 << btn2 << btn3 << std::endl;
    };
    virtual void setBtn2State(bool new_state)
    {
        btn2 = new_state;

        std::cout << btn1 << btn2 << btn3 << std::endl;
    };
    virtual void setBtn3State(bool new_state)
    {
        btn3 = new_state;

        std::cout << btn1 << btn2 << btn3 << std::endl;
    };
};

class UIStateAllEnabled : public UIState
{

public:
    UIStateAllEnabled()
    {
        btn1 = true;
        btn2 = true;
        btn3 = true;

        std::cout << btn1 << btn2 << btn3 << std::endl;
    }

};

class UIStateAllDisabled : public UIState
{

public:
    UIStateAllDisabled()
    {
        btn1 = false;
        btn2 = false;
        btn3 = false;

        std::cout << btn1 << btn2 << btn3 << std::endl;
    }

};

class UI
{
    UIState * currentState;

public:
    UI()
    {
        currentState = NULL;
    }

    ~UI()
    {
        if (currentState != NULL)
        {
            delete currentState;
            std::cout << "deleted current state" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void setState(UIState * new_state)
    {
        // should also check for if already current state?

        UIState * prevState = currentState;
        currentState = new_state;

        if (prevState != NULL)
        {
            delete prevState;

            std::cout << "deleted previous state" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void setBtn1State(bool new_state)
    {
        currentState->setBtn1State(new_state);
    };

    void setBtn2State(bool new_state)
    {
        currentState->setBtn2State(new_state);
    };

    void setBtn3State(bool new_state)
    {
        currentState->setBtn3State(new_state);
    };
};


int main()
{
    UI ui;

    // enable all buttons
    ui.setState(new UIStateAllEnabled);

    // Now say you want to change state of a particular button within this state.
    ui.setBtn1State(false);
    ui.setBtn3State(false);

    // switch to a completely new state, disable all buttons
    ui.setState(new UIStateAllDisabled);

    // customize within that sate
    ui.setBtn3State(true);

    return 0;
}
```